# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед словом "преступившие"?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая в выражении "отделение социализации детей(,) преступивших закон"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Обособляются (выделяются или отделяются) запятыми определительные обороты, т. е. определения, выраженные причастиями или прилагательными с зависимыми словами, КОГДА ОНИ СТОЯТ ПОСЛЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕМОГО СЛОВА.

*Детей* -- определяемое слово. *Преступивших закон* -- определительный оборот. Запятая в данном случае ставится:  ***"отделение социализации детей, преступивших закон".***

http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/262-obosoblennyeopredeleniyaiprilogeniya.html

Answer (score 1):

Распространенное определение, стоящее после определяемого слова, запятая ставится.